# How best to store a Python object for later evaluation?

Tags: python, object, scipy

I have written the following python code using a scipy function. The particular form of function `f` is irrelevant.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate.interpnd import LinearNDInterpolator    

def f(x, y):
    s = np.hypot(x, y)
    phi = np.arctan2(y, x)
    tau = s + s*(1-s)/5 * np.sin(6*phi)
    return 5*(1-tau) + tau

npts = 200
px, py = np.random.choice(x, npts), np.random.choice(y, npts)
ip = LinearNDInterpolator((px, py), f(px,py))
```

What kind of object is `ip`? I would like to store it in a file and evaluate it later as for example below.

```
x = np.linspace(-1,1,100)
y = np.linspace(-1,1,100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Ti = ip((X, Y))
```

What is a good way to store the object `ip` in a file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your object `ip` is an instance of the class `scipy.interpolate.interpnd.LinearNDInterpolator`. If you want to store the complete object to file, then you could use the [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) module from python's standard library.

Pickling an object and writing it to a (binary) file is quite straightforward:

```
import pickle
with open('data.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    # Write object `ip` to file
    pickle.dump(ip, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

Later loading the object again from file is equally straightforward:

```
with open('data.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    # Read out object `ip` from file
    ip = pickle.load(f)
```

Pickling does have a few disadvantages that are worth mentioning. Firstly, the pickle file that you write is not human-readable. Secondly, pickle files received from an untrusted source should never be loaded because of security risks.

Comment: Thank you. If I have an array or a dictionary of these object, I can pickle them just the same. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that should be possible (see also [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled)).

Answer (score 3):

Given that you know `f` and have access to `scipy`, I would posit that the simplest thing to do would be to just store `x` and `y`. This would avoid many of the pitfalls of a binary dump and allow you to store in a text format.

To store, you could use [`np.savetxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) to store the data:

```
np.savetxt('mystash.txt', np.stack((px, py), axis=1))
```

You can then have a simple loading procedure based on [`np.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html):

```
def load_interp(fname):
    px, py = np.loadtxt(fname, unpack=True)
    return LinearNDInterpolator((px, py), f(px,py))
```

This solution produces a very human readable text file with two columns of data, corresponding to the matching entries of `px` and `py`. The file is completely portable and editable. It is language independent, all at the cost of one extra line in the loader.

Comment: Originally I thought the object `ip` condensed all the data ((px, py), f(px,py)). But it seems it carries them around. So your method may be good. Does it work well when I have an array or a dictionary of many `ip`'s?

Comment: @Hans. If you always have the same number of samples, concatenate horizontally with more columns. Otherwise, I'd record the number of samples in each interpolator in a header line and concatenate vertically.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the "many of the pitfalls of a binary dump"?

Comment: @Hans. It's mostly an issue of portability. Binary files are sensitive to endianness, internal representations, magic numbers, etc. In other words, they are platform, language, version, etc dependent. Pickling is fairly robust, but you have to be careful, and it's not language agnostic. A human readable text file, on the other hand, is very difficult to screw up, especially if it only has ASCII characters.

Comment: @Hans. None of these considerations are likely to be a problem if you're just temporarily dumping to local disk for use within the same process.

Answer (score -1):

You can consider [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) for Python specific object serialization. Otherwise, you have to consider a `json` or `xml` format. Visit the link to understand more